# asp.net-mvc where do i put my own code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there any particular directory that i should put my code into in an asp.net mvc project

i have some extentions to the HtmlHelper class.  Right now i have it sitting in the Content folder.  is this correct?  is there a better soluiton?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I usually create a separate project (or projects) for my own code, including my data layer, as class libraries.  I then reference the libraries in my MVC web site.

Comment: Indeed - That's what I'd do also.

Comment: You advocate putting HtmlHelper extensions in a data layer?

Comment: No -- I advocate using separate libraries for your own code.  My helper extensions would go in a MVC libary.  My data layer would go in a different library.

Answer (score 4):

you can put code wherever you want, but typically you want things organised. heres how i do it:

2 assemblies

- MyProject.Domain

this contains all my domain code; business logic and entities

- MyProject.Web

this contains controller code, views and assets like css/images

Your HtmlHelpers belong in the .Web project because they are mvc related (nothing to do with the domain). You probably want a new folder called Helpers or Extentions. Its really up to you, the key point is to decide where something belongs and to namespace it accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what everyone else said, here's how one of my solutions would look like:

1. 1- MyProject.WebUI
2. 2- MyProject.DomainModel
3. 3- MyProject.Test
4. 4- MyProject.Extensions

This extensions project is new to me (actually since I knew about extension methods). It usually concludes sub-folders describing what the extension methods are used for, for your particular case, the folder name would be **HtmlHelpers**. I then reference this project (or its output library when using elsewhere).
 HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to re-use the same HTMLHelper extensions in different ASP.NET MVC projects, I'd suggest putting them in a class library which is completely seperate from your project.